# How to find out what error I'm dealing with when Kohana site does nothing but throw error 500?

Tags: php, kohana-3

A client has a site running on Kohana 3.0.3. He broke something on it (he's not even entirely sure what, likely he only modified some data in the DB through the admin panel) and now every page returns the not so informant error 500.

From what I understand the error page is actually generated by Kohana (and not by the host). So how do I go about finding what the error actually is. I google a bit, but couldn't find anything specific about debugging a non-working instance of Kohana. I checked the logs in the tmp folder, but no entries appear there for current month.

Is there some debug flag that I can set to be able to see error codes? Or some log file that logs all errors that are returned as 500?

Edit: I have access to the FTP and database, but not to the server admin panel.

Comment: Read the error log of your web server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Unfortunately the host is the only thing I do not have access to. Assuming Kohana is throwing those 500 errors at me, it's very likely that specific error was not registered by the server?

Comment: If PHP throws an error it shows up in the web server error log. If you don't have access to it you can usually define your own error log within PHP itself: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ini_set("log_errors", 1); ini_set("error_log", "/path/to/php_errorlog.log");` You should make sure this is executed as early as possible by PHP.

Comment: 500 error is always generated by web server. it is `HTTP Internal server error`. If you have no access to the error logs it is going to be very tough. Start checking with your `.htaccess` file for infinite loops (if you have any).

Comment: @bansi From what I understand Kohana catches all the errors and returns the error page on it's own (in fact the error page returns code 200 rather than 500). The returned text "Error 500 Internal Server Error" is actually located in modules\website\classes\controller\public\error.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of good old fashioned reverse engineering I found out that errors are hidden when the `IN_PRODUCTION` variable is set to true. In my case the value was being initialized in the `bootstrap.php` file in the `application` directory.

I had to switch from:

```
define('IN_PRODUCTION', true);
```

to:

```
define('IN_PRODUCTION', false);
```

And now I can see what exactly is breaking.

Edit: The source of the problem on the Kohana site was an error in the frontend menu meta data. So if no part of a Kohana site is available (admin panel included), it's possible that there are errors in the menu structure (my client managed to break it using nothing but the admin panel, so it's probably a bug in the engine/menu module). It's also possible the code is exclusive to that site.

Comment: nice you got the error. you can accept this an answer, so someone will later find this useful. luckily your error was in PHP code. For actual 500 errors it is bit more complicated than this, without web server error log. The web server can generating 500 error before even PHP gets a change to parse your .php file.